# Is this correct method of calculating $1^{st}$ and $2^{nd}$ derivative?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

$$f(x) = \sqrt{(x+1)}$$

$$f(x) = {(x+1)^{1/2}} $$

$$f'(x) = ({\frac 1 2} x)^{-1/2} $$

$$f''(x) = \Big(\Big(-{\frac 1 2}\Big){\frac 1 2} x\Big)^{-3/2} = - \frac 1 4 x ^ {-3/2} $$

Comment: Derivative of $f(x)^n$ is $nf(x)^{n - 1}f'(x)$. In your case $f(x) = x + 1$ and $n = 1/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $f(x) = g(h(x))$ where $g(u) = \sqrt u = u^{1/2}$ and $h(x) = x+1$.

The derivatives of these are $g'(u) = \frac12 u^{-1/2}$ and $h'(x) = 1$.

The chain rule then says that 
$$f'(x) = g'(h(x)) \cdot h'(x) = \frac12 h(x)^{-1/2} \cdot 1 = \frac12(x+1)^{-1/2}$$

Continuing, the second derivative then becomes
$$f''(x) = \frac12 \cdot \left(-\frac12\right)(x+1)^{-3/2} \cdot 1 = -\frac14(x+1)^{-3/2}$$

Answer (score 1):

we have $$f(x)=(x+1)^{1/2}$$ then we get
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x+1)^{-1/2}$$
$$f''(x)=-\frac{1}{4}(x+1)^{-3/2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, but you're very close.

$[g(x)^n]'=ng(x)^{n-1}g'(x)$

So you have a mistake on the first derivative as the $+1$ shouldn't disappear